# Graphing multiplex network

Tags: r, matlab, igraph, network-analysis

I would like to know the best software to graph a multiplex network. I have tried to do what I want in Gephi but it is unable to produce what I need. I know how to use R or Matlab so tools using this software is preferred.

Basically, I want to visualize reciprocity. For example, say we have four people and two periods. In the first period each person gives a gift to another person. In the second period each player gives a new gift and may choose to reciprocate the gifts from the first period.

First, I want to graph the period one network using some form of spring algorithm pulling linked nodes closer together and repelling unlinked nodes. Gehpi can do this very easily.

What Gephi can not do is display the peroid two connections in a different color and side by side. Instead Gephi lays each connection over one another so you cannot see the reciprocated gifts. At this stage I will use the spring algorithm again so the reciprocated nodes move closer together and unreciprocated nodes are repelled. This will give me an aggregate network visualization to accompany the statistics I calculate.

[This image might give a good indication of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhIAS.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you look at [Muxviz](http://muxviz.net). There might be a slight learning curve, and you'd need to get your data there in a desired fashion, but Muxviz can be very powerful.

If you're only looking for a quick-fix for a one-off, you could try plotting your layers in igraph  with the same `layout`, (or why not Gephi exporting as svg/pdf) and then superimpose them by hand in Illustrator.